# Changing visibility of multiple collections at once

Tags: collections

How can I change the view layer visibility of selected (sub)collections all at once?

[image: collection]

Comment: are u open to a python script solution?

Comment: Yes, I am open to any script that works

Answer (score 1):

In outliner, tap A to select all, right click on collection -> visibility -> enable/disable in viewport/render

Comment: That didn't help with what I am trying to do unfortunately.

Comment: maybe it would be a good idea to tell us why it didn't help?